# Redis mass insertion: protocol vs inline commands

Tags: redis, protocols, bulk, bulk-load

For my task I need to load a bulk of data into Redis as soon as possible. It looks like this article is right about my case: https://redis.io/topics/mass-insert

The article starts from giving an example of using multiple inline `SET` commands with *redis-cli*. Then they proceed to generating Redis protocol and again use it with *redis-cli*. They don't explain the reasons or benefits of using Redis protocol.

Using of Redis protocol is a bit harder and it generates a bit more traffic. I wonder, what are the reasons to use Redis protocol rather than simple one-line commands? Probably despite the fact the data is larger, it is easier (and faster) for Redis to parse it?

Comment: > to feed it to Redis as fast as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good point.

> Only a small percentage of clients support **non-blocking I/O**, and not
>   all the clients are able to **parse the replies in an efficient way in
>   order to maximize throughput**. For all this reasons the preferred way
>   to mass import data into Redis is to generate a text file containing
>   the Redis protocol, in raw format, in order to call the commands
>   needed to insert the required data.

What I understood is that you emulate a client when you use Redis protocol directly, which would benefit from the highlighted points.

Based on the docs you provided, I tried these scripts:

### **test.rb**

```
def gen_redis_proto(*cmd)
    proto = ""
    proto << "*"+cmd.length.to_s+"\r\n"
    cmd.each{|arg|
        proto << "$"+arg.to_s.bytesize.to_s+"\r\n"
        proto << arg.to_s+"\r\n"
    }
    proto
end
(0...100000).each{|n|
    STDOUT.write(gen_redis_proto("SET","Key#{n}","Value#{n}"))
}
```

### **test_no_protocol.rb**

```
(0...100000).each{|n|
    STDOUT.write("SET Key#{n} Value#{n}\r\n")
}
```

---

- `ruby test.rb > 100k_prot.txt`
- `ruby test_no_protocol.rb > 100k_no_prot.txt`
- `time cat 100k.txt | redis-cli --pipe`
- `time cat 100k_no_prot.txt | redis-cli --pipe`

I've got these results:

```
teixeira: ~/stackoverflow $ time cat 100k.txt | redis-cli --pipe
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
Last reply received from server.
errors: 0, replies: 100000

real    0m0.168s
user    0m0.025s
sys 0m0.015s
(5 arquivo(s), 6,6Mb)

teixeira: ~/stackoverflow $ time cat 100k_no_prot.txt | redis-cli --pipe
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
Last reply received from server.
errors: 0, replies: 100000

real    0m0.433s
user    0m0.026s
sys 0m0.012s
```